# Referncing specific variable in ArrayList object

Tags: java, arrays, object, methods, interface

My questions involves searching for a specific variable within an object in an ArrayList and returning the variable.  One of the issues for me is that the Student object contains multiple variable fields.

I am trying to locate a specific variable in an object and then return it from an array list.

This is the main method:

```
    Student s1 = new Student ("student1", 123, "MIS");
    Student s2 = new Student("student2", 231, "Finance");
    Student s3 = new Student ("student3", 432, "MIS");
    Student s4 = new Student ("student4", 438, "Marketing");
    Student s5 = new Student ("student5", 429, "MIS");
    Student s6 = new Student ("student6", 215, "Accounting");
    Student s7 = new Student ("student7", 287, "MIS");
    Student s8 = new Student ("student8", 401, "MIS");

    ArrayList<Student> myList = new ArrayList<Student>();
    myList.add(s1);
    myList.add(s2);
    myList.add(s3);
    myList.add(s4);
    myList.add(s5);
    myList.add(s6);
    myList.add(s7);
    myList.add(s8);

    StudentDatabaseImplementation st = new StudentDatabaseImplementation(); 
    st.setTheListOfStudents(myList);
    st.printTheListOfStudents(myList);


    st.getStudent(429);
    System.out.println("The name of the student : "+    
    st.getStudent(429).getName());
```

And the within the Student class that I have created I wrote:

```
   public class Student{
   private String name;
   private int CWID, ID;
   private String major, maj;

   private ArrayList<Student> myList = new ArrayList<Student>()

   public Student(String name, int CWID, String major)
   {this.name=name;CWID=ID; String Major = maj;}

   public String getName() {return name;}

   public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}

   public ArrayList<Student> getAllStudents() {return myList;}

   -->public Student getStudent(int CWID){if(myList.contains CWID)   
     {getName();}}

   public void setTheListOfStudents(ArrayList<Student> myList) {
   this.myList = myList;}

   public String getMajorName() {return majorName;}

   public void setMajorName(String majorName) {this.majorName = majorName;}

   public int getCWID() {return CWID;}

   public void setCWID(int studentId) {this.studentCWID = studentCWID;}

   private String majorName;
   private int studentCWID;
```

Is there something else I can do to return the user's name?

Comment: Your code looks fine.  What is wrong with using your current getter to get the student name?

Comment: How does your `StudentDatabaseImplementation` look like?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I wish I could but for this assignment the getStudent method is required.  However, myList.contains CWID will not run because it says the variable CWID can not be found.

Comment: here the error: `if(myList.contains CWID) --> if(myList.contains(CWID))`. You should also implement equals() method.

Comment: @MuratK. I have to use an interface to implement onto the StudentDatabaseImplementation class, so I just copy and pasted the main code over onto there as well.  Is that wrong?

Comment: You do not provide specifics for your implementation of StudentDatabaseImplementation. First your getStudent method is not correct. The myList.contains needs to search against a Student Object and not your CWID integer. Second, the contains will return a true/false. Let's suppose you find a match after you fix that line, then following line, getName(), needs to call getName() against the matching Student object.

Answer (score 0):

Although your code seems fine, you can override the `toString()` method of `Student` class and make it return the user's name.

```
public class Student {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getName();
    }

}
```

then you can call

```
System.out.println("The name of the student : "+    
st.getStudent(429));
```

Comment: I have to use the getStudent method.

Comment: it's there: `st.getStudent(429)`

Comment: The public Student getStudent(int CWID) method still has to return a Student value.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should implement `getStudent` method. It return null, if student is not found, or the Student with CWID equals to the CWID parameter, if in the list there is at least Student with that CWID.

```
public Student getStudent(int CWID){
    return myList.stream().filter(s -> s.getCWID()==CWID).findAny().orElse(null);
}
```

I suggest you to evaluate a Map in order to store the students.

```
Map<int,Student>
```

where the key is the CWID. In this way you should not iterate to find the student.

Comment: `Student foundStudent= new Student("",0,"");`

      `  for(int i=0; i<Student.size();i++) {`
              if(CWID==Students.get(i).getCWID())                 
                  { foundStudent=Students.get(i);
     }
}`

This is what I ended up going with, it was the only thing I could get to work.

Comment: I'd use the myList.contains(CWID) method, but it works only if you implement the equals method in the Student class as I suggested in the answer.

Comment: Your method you put above...I was just wondering how you would use that in the public Student getStudent(int CWID) context.  Whenever I try to call the boolean method, it will not return a Student variable.